# Send data to Bluetooth module from android terminal

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to control my arduino 4-relay module thru bluetooth hc-06.
I already did it by Tasker and plugins but it very slow and buggy.

All I need is bunch of commands in shell, doing connect to serial bt and sending chars.

May be python script ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using an app called [Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Qwerty.BluetoothTerminal&hl=en) for this, and I can say that it works very well!

You basically get a simple Serial monitor, and you can select the Bluetooth device you want to connect to. A screenshot of the app on my phone:

[image: A screenshot of the app]

You can set whether you want a secure connection and the app also allows you to view the received/transmitted data in hex form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i am looking for a complete solution. After voice command trigger should execute some thing - code or script. becouse i am not a programmer i am trying build solution out of different bricks such as automate, tasker and plugins

Comment: So I assume you've already tried [this tasker plugin)[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_rblackmore245.Arduino_Bluetooth&hl=en]? I can't really help you, because I've never used Tasker myself.

Comment: Yep! It is good, but need to be open , it can't run as a service. I used it with Automate. Huh...